# How to get request in Spring REST controller depending on JSON requirement?

Tags: java, json, spring

```
public ResponseEntity<TastyDashResponse> order(@PathVariable("restaurantId") String restaurantId,
                                                       @RequestBody RestaurantOrderBook request,
                                                       @RequestBody ExpItems exp) {}
```

I have two `Objects` `RestaurantOrderBook` and `ExpItems`. Incoming request should have either of them and the other becomes optional.

How to achieve this within same method. When this `code` I get `404 bad request`. please help with it.

Comment: I guess the problem is in multiple @RequestBody annotations. Why you don't combine `RestaurantOrderBook ` and `ExpItems ` into one DTO object?

Comment: you can change `@PathVariable` to `@RequestParam(value = "restaurantId", required = false)` if the parameters in your request are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use two @RequestBody as it can bind to a single object .
solution create one object that will capture all the relevent data  like this this :

```
 public class Data {
  private  String restaurantId;
  private RestaurantOrderBook request;
  private ExpItems exp;
  getters/setters 
  } 



public ResponseEntity<TastyDashResponse> order(@RequestBody Data data) {}
```